# Exception thrown with OpenCV's SVM training, c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I have a problem with the Support Vector Machine , coding with visual studio, c++.
Tried to replicate the example of the tutorial at the following link 
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d1/d73/tutorial_introduction_to_svm.html and the situation is
(having a breakpoint at "return 0;" line)

1) In debug , x64 I run the solution, and after "return 0" statement I have an exception thrown
at memory location (not unhandled, luckily) and then the program exit correctly.

2) In release, x64, I run the solution, and after "return 0" statement I have an exception thrown
at memory location but clicking on "continue" button, this appears (of mat.inl.hpp)

```
inline
void Mat::release()
{
    if( u && CV_XADD(&u->refcount, -1) == 1 )
        deallocate();
    u = NULL;
    datastart = dataend = datalimit = data = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < dims; i++)
    ---->    size.p[i] = 0; <----- // (that's the exact line)!
#ifdef _DEBUG
    flags = MAGIC_VAL;
    dims = rows = cols = 0;
    if(step.p != step.buf)
    {
        fastFree(step.p);
        step.p = step.buf;
        size.p = &rows;
    }
#endif
}
```

And I have the correct exit of the program only clicking on "continue" bottom several times.
This happens only in release mode.
How to fix it?

Comment: What exception is thrown?

Comment: Exception thrown at 0x00007FF8E3533FB8 in SVM classifier.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000A4E8AFCA48. . Thanks @Demosthenes

Comment: I think all (or at least most) of OpenCV exceptions have an accompanying text, stating what is wrong. Not sure how to display them in Visual C++.

Comment: Alternative approach: when it breaks there, what is size.p, and what is i?

Comment: Don't know ! Can't test this on release mode. Anyway, I haven't written that part of code, it's written out of my soruce code. It belongs to mat.inl.hpp @Demosthenes